# Why is my rails.png 404 for a new app of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just added a new Rails app on my server (Phusion Passenger with Apache), but the assets/rails.png is not found. Could someone explain why this would happen for a new app? and how can I fix it and prevent it in the future new apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running webrick on your dev machine with

```
rails s -e production
```

or check the log on the server to see what error you get. Most likely you haven't compiled the assets with:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

that will give you a no route error on images. See this page for [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) details.

Comment: I should mention this is on a phusion passenger apache server. Also, it was this: `rake assets:precompile`